# How do I unit test a controller method that has the attribute applied?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I create own custom attribute for authentication for web API as per requirement.
And also I created the unit test project for test web API when I test method it tests successfully but method attribute not tested so how I unit test web API custom attribute.

**API code:**

```
[HttpGet]
[AuthenticateTokenFilter]
public dynamic CheckUserSeession(string UserID, string AccessID)
{
    try
    {                   
        TestAPIModel users = new TestAPIModel();

        users.Name = "RAM";
        users.ID = "12";
        users.UserName = "M";

        var loAPIResponse = new APIResultItem<TestAPIModel> { Data = users, HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, ErrorGUID = null };
        return loAPIResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }
}
```

`[AuthenticateTokenFilter]` is my custom attribute, here the code:

```
 public class AuthenticateTokenFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext foAction)
        {
            if (!CheckUserAccessID(foAction.ActionArguments))
            {
                UserLoginResponseModel loResponseModel = new UserLoginResponseModel();
                loResponseModel.Message = "AuthenticationFailed";
                if (foAction.ActionArguments != null)
                {
                    if (foAction.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("AccessID") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(foAction.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("AccessID").ToString()))
                        loResponseModel.AccessId = foAction.ActionArguments["AccessID"].ToString();
                    if (foAction.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("UserID") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(foAction.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("UserID").ToString()))
                        loResponseModel.UserId = foAction.ActionArguments["UserID"].ToString();
                }
                var loInvalidUserSession = new APIResultItem<UserLoginResponseModel> { Data = loResponseModel, HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ErrorGUID = null };
                foAction.Response = foAction.Request.CreateResponse(loInvalidUserSession);
            }
        }  



    public bool CheckUserAccessID(Dictionary<string, object> foActionArguments)
    {
        bool lbIsValidUserSession = false;
        try
        {
            if (foActionArguments.ContainsKey("AccessID") && foActionArguments.ContainsKey("UserID"))
            {
                CommonBAL loCommonBAL = new CommonBAL();
                lbIsValidUserSession = loCommonBAL.CheckUserSession(Convert.ToString(foActionArguments["AccessID"]), Convert.ToString(foActionArguments["UserID"]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return lbIsValidUserSession;
    }
}
```

**Test code:**

```
[TestMethod()]
[AuthenticateTokenFilter]
public void TestUserSessionSuccess()
{
    TestAPIModel loResponseModel = new TestAPIModel();
    var loExpectedAPIResponse = new APIResultItem<TestAPIModel> { Data = loResponseModel, HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, ErrorGUID = null };

    TestControllerBuilder loTestBuilder = new TestControllerBuilder();
    TNHDefaultWebAPIController loAPIController = new TNHDefaultWebAPIController();
    string lsUserId = "BA893C8B-6DC1-428A-BEF4-0C86389CD58F", lsAccessId = "D95DB230-2A80-4E33-992B-AC46F97DAAB7";
    var loActualResult = (APIResultItem<TestAPIModel>)loAPIController.CheckUserSeession(lsUserId, lsAccessId);
    Assert.AreEqual(loExpectedAPIResponse.HttpStatusCode, loActualResult.HttpStatusCode);
}
```

How can I test AuthenticateTokenFilter attribute?

Comment: Attribute is metadata. You would need to run an integration test that will take the attribute into account when invoked. Otherwise you can test the attribute directly to assert that it behaves as desired. Besides that is the least of your problems as I see a few issues with the provided code as presented.

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: What does `CheckUserAccessID` do? Not seeing it in the sample code

Comment: its return bool, for check valid user

Comment: Obviously it returns bool based on how it is used. How is it implemented. Show the code.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: Be wary of trying to test everything all in one test. This will lead to your tests becoming fragile and difficult to maintain. @Nkosi is right, if you want to test the attribute, test the attribute (in isolation). It's meta data as a far as the method your testing is concerned so not really relevant to the test of that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you review the structure of your code and clean it up. Outside of that, if you want to test the functionality of the attribute you would need to create an instance of the attribute and provide the necessary dependencies needed for it to be exercised to completion.

For example

```
[TestClass]
public class AuthenticateTokenFilterTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void AuthenticateTokenFilter_UnAuthorized() {
        //Arrange
        var actionContext = new HttpActionContext() {
            //...you basically need to set the necessay properties used by the attribute here
        };
        var subject = new AuthenticateTokenFilter();
        //Act
        subject.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, actionContext.Response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

The attribute appears to make heavy use of the `actionContext.ActionArguments`, so create a dictionary that contains the desired values and use that for the test. They can be modified to cover the different test cases for the attribute.